# Ubuntu 17.04 use always OpenGL 3.3 with radeon driver

Tags: radeon, opengl, ubuntu-drivers

i'm new to Ubuntu but not to Linux or BSD at all. I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on an Intel q6600 Processor with 4gb RAM an an AMD Radeon HD 6850. The graphics card support OpenGL 4.1 and Ubuntu uses the open source radeon driver. I want to use the Unreal Engine 4 but the Engine won't start because it wants OpenGL 4.3 but glxinfo says I have only OpenGL 3.3. How can I update the driver or the  System to get OpenGL 4?

Comment: You can't. Radeon doesn't support opengl4 yet, and it's unclear when and if it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever) is right. According to [www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature](https://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature/) the Radeon HD 6000 series (Northern Islands chip series with Barts core) is limited to OpenGL 3.3. AMD graphics cards only with "...CYPRESS, CAYMAN and ARUBA..." cores are supported by OpenGL 4.1, but not by OpenGL 4.5.